# Order of lewis acidity for BBr3, BCl3, BMe3, BH3, BPh3?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

In case of $\ce{BCl_3}$ vs $\ce{BH3}$, which one is the controlling factor?

1) Is it p-pi p-pi interaction in $\ce{BCl_3}$ that makes it weaker than  $\ce{BH3}$?

2) Or is it the -I effect of $\ce{Cl}$ dominating over others, despite of p-pi p-pi interaction that makes it stronger than $\ce{BH3}$ as well as $\ce{BMe3}$?

Comment: I know you didn’t mention it specifically, but here’s something related that’s pretty interesting: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic990713m

Answer (score 1):

BBr3 is more acidic than BCl3 due to weaker pi back bonding in BBr3 as compared to BCl3.BCl3 is stronger acid than BH3 due to electron withdrawing effect of Cl make B becomes more electron deficient despite of pi back bonding in BCl3. Due to steric reason BMe3 is stronger acid than BPh3.